# Query a multi-valued column

Tags: oracle, lookup, multivalue

I have a multi-valued column , MISC_CONTENT with the following string in the column:

```
amount = 7995 ;channel = SXXXN21 ;group_header = NPS099 ;currency = EUR
```

How can retrieve the value NPS099 by lookup with group_header?

Comment: use the SQL LIKE operator

Comment: LIKE doesn't work in multi-valued, and the length value/sequence of group_header is random

Comment: You said _How can retrieve the value NPS099 by lookup with group_header?_ but it sounds like you're asking how to retrieve the value associated with `group_header`.  if so, the regexp_substr answer below from @TimBiegeleisen looks like a reasonable approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'amount = 7995 ;channel = SXXXN21 ;group_header = NPS099 ;currency = EUR' AS col FROM dual
)

SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '(^|\s|;)group_header = (.*?)\s*(;|$)', 1,1,NULL,2)
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there any restriction on the substring from the syntax? some of the values are truncated in my result

Comment: I can only answer based on data which I can actually.  My answer works for what you showed us.  If you have an edge case in mind, then please reveal it.

Comment: it truncated  when hit the whitespace, for, example, ABCD EFGH become ABCD